# How to run jshint in emacs web-mode?

Tags: emacs, jshint

As stated on the web-mode.org page, since May 2014 `web-mode` supports jshint.

I've been using `jshint` in `js-mode`, for which purpose I installed flycheck and added the following setting to the .emacs file:

```
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda () (flycheck-mode t)))
```

I would also like to make jshint work in `web-mode`, but failed to do so. Here’s what I tried:

open `.js` file

`M-x web-mode`

`M-x web-mode-jshint`

`M-x flycheck`

But no luck. Could you please suggest how to make `jshint` work in emacs's `web-mode`?

**UPDATE:** fxbois pointed out below that the only command that needs to be executed is 
`M-x web-mode-jshint`. This works on regular `.js` files, but does not work on `.js.erb` files (which are recognized by the regular `web-mode`). So the next part of my question is, does anybody know how to make `web-mode-jshint` work with `.js.erb` files?

Comment: `.js.erb` files don't (necessarily) contain valid JavaScript until after Ruby processes them. How do you expect JSHint to be able to parse them?

Comment: Well, if I open a `.js.erb` file in `js-mode`, JSHint will work, but will flag the embedded ruby tags (<% %>) as incorrect. In `web-mode`, however, it doesn't work at all. So JSHint is able to parse a `.js.erb` file, only not in `web-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have to execute `M-x web-mode-jshint`

(of course, `jshint` should be installed)

Comment: This works on regular .js files, but doesn't work on .js.erb files. Normal `web-mode` highlights syntax of a .js.erb file, but running `web-mode-jshint` after activating `web-mode` does not turn on `jshint`. Simply executing `web-mode-jshint` in a .js.erb file neither activates `jshint` nor performs syntax highlighting :-(

Comment: do you have any error in your ```** messages **``` buffer ?

Comment: No errors. Curious thing though: when I open a regular `.js` file and do `M-x web-mode-j Tab`, the command autocompletes to `web-mode-jshint`. When I open a `.js.erb` file and do `M-x web-mode-j Tab`, there is no autocompletion. I can then enter the `web-mode`, and once in there do `M-x web-mode-j Tab`, and then the command autocompletes to `web-mode-jshint`, but nothing happens. The only message I get is "You can run the command `web-mode-jshint' with C-c C-j".

Comment: Could you open web-mode.el and set the absolute path of your jshint binary please

Comment: I apologize, but my emacs-fu is very poor. Where and how exactly do I set the absolute path to jshint binary (which, I believe, is`~/.npm/jshint/2.5.11/package/bin/jshint`) in web-mode.el?

Comment: Then again, since `web-mode` works on `.js` files (but fails to work on `.js.erb` files), it must be aware of jshint in my system, no?

Comment: search ```"jshint" "--extract=auto" (buffer-file-name)))``` and replace ```"jshint"``` by ```"~/.npm/jshint/2.5.11/package/bin/jshint"```

Comment: Replaced `jshint` for the absolute path to the jshint binary, but nothing changed. Recompiled the folder; updated the `web-mode` package, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this in the past 20 minutes and found that `web-mode-jshint` does not run automatically, use C-c C-j to evaluate the buffer manually. I am still searching for a way to run the evaluation automatically.

(IMO) It is unfortunate that `web-mode-jshint` does not integrate existing jshint solutions, e.g. flycheck, but implements its own highlighting.